# My Child window not closed in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I’m working in WPF and I’m facing an issue regarding NDI container
In my MainWindow Xaml I have the MainMdiContainer

```
<mdi:MdiContainer Theme="Aero" mdi:MdiChild.Closed="MdiChild_Closed"  Margin="0,0,0,80" Name="MainMdiContainer" Grid.Row="1" Background="{x:Null}">
 </mdi:MdiContainer>
```

Of course I have another xaml page named “Registration” and  I also have a button in mainWindow to open the mdiChild

```
Public Sub btnAddUser_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnAddUser.Click
        MainMdiContainer.Children.Clear()
        MainMdiContainer.Children.Add(New MdiChild() With { _
         .Title = "Πρόγραμμα Εσωτερικής Διαχείρισης Διορισμός Επιτροπής και Χρηστών", _
         .Height = (System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - 500), _
          .Width = (System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - 430), _
         .Style = Nothing, _
         .Content = New Registration() _
        })
    End Sub

Public Sub MdiChild_Closed(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        For Each child As MdiChild In MainMdiContainer.Children.ToList()
            If (child.Name.ToString().Contains("mdiChildRegistration")) Then
                MainMdiContainer.Children.Remove(child)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Until this stage everything goes fine  and the mdiChild opens
Now I want to close the child window by pushing a button

```
Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Dim mainWin As New MainWindow
    Dim mdiCont As MdiContainer = mainWin.MainMdiContainer
    mainWin.MdiChild_Closed(sender, e)

    End Sub
```

But the mdiChild it not close… in fact  the Childern  in  mdiCont is empty.
When I add a Childern

```
<mdi:MdiChild IsTabStop="False" />
```

In MainWindow then the Childern  in  mdiCont is not empty it has one Child which is closed when I'm try to open my child whindow by pressing the button.
I suspect that something in the add procedure has to do with but I don’t know what.
Is there someone to assist me?

Comment: What MDI container are you using? Does it support binding as items source?

Comment: I use this   xmlns:mdi="clr-namespace:WPF.MDI;assembly=WPF.MDI"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've made it to clese the child window
And all comes from the child code behind

```
Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
        Dim mainWin As MainWindow = Economy.Application.Current.MainWindow
        mainWin.MainMdiContainer.Children.Clear()
```

In the declaration of mainWin it has to be refered as

> 'Object.Application.Current.MainWindow'

in order to transfer the child window attributes and have the ability to clear it.
Not Removed because the Remove is not clear the child window.
Thank you very much for @dymanoid.